# OpenGL **sometimes** renders one point (of 65,000)

Tags: c++, opengl, terrain, heightmap

I am loading a heightmap and trying to render the results as a series of GL_POINTS, as the code currently is it will **sometimes** render one point in the center of my screen (no matter where the camera is located- and I have tried spreading out the points further to see if they were stacked ontop of each other). As much as minimising Visual Studio and maximising it again could stop or start the point being rendered. You will notice I have the line:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

commented out - this is because this line will stop all rendering of my 'terrain' completely. The rest of my render loop consists purely of setting up the PROJECTION and MODELVIEW matricies and calling a clear() and swapbuffers() - (which is all working correctly because I resourced the information from a book and tested it with the generic multicoloured triangle).

Terrain Class:

```
class Terrain 
{
public:
Terrain(char* pFile){
    if(!LoadTerrain(pFile))
    {
        OutputDebugString("Loading terain failed.\n");
    }
};

~Terrain(){};

void Draw()
{
    glPushMatrix();
    //glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // Uncommenting this causes me to see nothing at all

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    GLenum a = glGetError(); // 1281

    glPointSize(5.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, mNumberPoints);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 

    glPopMatrix();
}

private:
GLuint mVBO;
int mWidth;
int mHeight;
int mNumberPoints;

bool LoadTerrain(char* pFile)
{
    FILE* filePtr;
    int error;
    unsigned int count;
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;
    int imageSize, i, j, k, index;
    unsigned char* bitmapImage;
    unsigned char height;

    error = fopen_s(&filePtr, pFile, "rb");
    if(error)
        return false;
    count = fread(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, filePtr);
    if(count != 1)
        return false;
    count = fread(&bih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, filePtr);
    if(count != 1)
        return false;

    mWidth = bih.biWidth;
    mHeight = bih.biHeight;
    mNumberPoints = mWidth * mHeight;
    imageSize = mWidth * mHeight * 3; // 3 values * width * height = total data size

    bitmapImage = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    fseek(filePtr, bfh.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    count = fread(bitmapImage, 1, imageSize, filePtr);
    if(count != imageSize)
        return false;
    error = fclose(filePtr);
    if(error)
        return false;

    float* mapArray = new float[imageSize];
    k = 0; 
    for(j = 0; j < mHeight; j++)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < mWidth; i++)
        {
            height = bitmapImage[k];

            index = (mHeight * j) + i;

            mapArray[k++] = 10*(float)i;
            mapArray[k++] = (float)height;
            mapArray[k++] = 10*(float)j;

            /*OutputDebugString(convertInt(i).c_str());
            OutputDebugString(",");
            OutputDebugString(convertInt(height).c_str());
            OutputDebugString(",");
            OutputDebugString(convertInt(j).c_str());
            OutputDebugString("\n");*/
        }
    }


    // COPY MAP ARRAY INTO BUFFERS
    glGenBuffers(1, &mVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * imageSize, mapArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    delete [] bitmapImage;
    bitmapImage = 0;

    return true;
};

string convertInt(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return "0";
    string temp="";
    string returnvalue="";
    while (number>0)
    {
        temp+=number%10+48;
        number/=10;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
        returnvalue+=temp[temp.length()-i-1];
    return returnvalue;
}
};
```

Notes: Some may notice this is connected to my last question; but my last question was a mistake correctly answered (and I marked it as such) so that thread isn't getting much attention. Very much unintentional spam.

**EDIT::** The rest of my render loop::

```
// Set up projection
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45, 1024.0/768.0, 1, 1000);
// Set up camera view
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0,20, -50,
    0,0,0,
    0,1,0);
glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

**EDIT:** Even more of my code:

Main.CPP

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "Engine.h"
#include "Terrain.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASS wc;
HWND hWnd;
HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRC;
MSG msg;
BOOL quit = FALSE;
float theta = 0.0f;

// register window class
wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon( NULL, IDI_APPLICATION );
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( BLACK_BRUSH );
wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "PointCloudTerrainClass";
RegisterClass( &wc );

// create main window
hWnd = CreateWindow( 
    "PointCloudTerrainClass", "Point Cloud Terrain", 
    WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
    0, 0, 1024, 768,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL );

// enable OpenGL for the window
Engine mEngine = Engine(hWnd, &hDC, &hRC);
// Set shaders
glewInit();

Terrain t = Terrain("heightmap.bmp");

while ( !quit )
{
    if ( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE )  )
    {
        if ( msg.message == WM_QUIT ) 
        {
            quit = TRUE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
    } 
    // OpenGL STUFF
    {

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //gluPerspective(45, 1024.0/768.0, 1, 1000);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        //gluLookAt(cameraData[0],cameraData[1], cameraData[2],
        //        0,0,0,
        //        0,1,0);

        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //glUseProgram(program);

        t.Draw();

        // STOP RENDER STUFF

        glFlush();
        SwapBuffers( hDC );
    }

}

mEngine.DisableOpenGL();

DestroyWindow( hWnd );

return msg.wParam;

}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

switch (message)
{

case WM_CREATE:
    return 0;

case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage( 0 );
    return 0;

case WM_DESTROY:
    return 0;

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch ( wParam )
    {

    case VK_ESCAPE:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    return 0;

default:
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );

}
}
```

Engine.H:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl\GL.h>
#include <gl\GLU.h>

class Engine
{
public:

Engine(HWND hWnd, HDC * hDC, HGLRC * hRC)
{
    EnableOpenGL(hWnd, hDC, hRC);
}

~Engine()
{

}

void DisableOpenGL()
{
    wglMakeCurrent( NULL, NULL );
    wglDeleteContext( *mhRC );
    ReleaseDC( mhWnd, *mhDC );
}


private:
HWND mhWnd;
HDC * mhDC;
HGLRC * mhRC;

void EnableOpenGL(HWND hWnd, HDC * hDC, HGLRC * hRC)
{
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
    int format;

    // get the device context (DC)
    *hDC = GetDC( hWnd );

    // set the pixel format for the DC
    ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
    pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    format = ChoosePixelFormat( *hDC, &pfd );
    SetPixelFormat( *hDC, format, &pfd );

    // create and enable the render context (RC)
    *hRC = wglCreateContext( *hDC );
    wglMakeCurrent( *hDC, *hRC );

    mhWnd = hWnd;
    mhDC = hDC;
    mhRC = hRC;
}
};
```

Comment: It is very unusual that enabling the client state `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` causes you to see nothing. This is often one state that is enabled and never disabled. In the deprecated fixed-function pipeline there was no reason to ever disable `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` because you could not create unique vertex positions any other way; it was the one property of a vertex array that was always necessary. Q3 is [famously noted](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/quake3/johnc_glopt.html) for never disabling it. These days you can use `gl_VertexID` and a constant array of points in your vertex shader if you want.

Comment: I think your actual problem is that you are only drawing 3 points (final parameter to `glDrawArrays (...)`). Surely your terrain has more than 3 points total. Otherwise it is just a plane.

Comment: If I draw the full number of points I see nothing (regardless of GL_VERTEX_ARRAY being enabled or disabled it seems.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman Oh no I stand corrected- It does still *sometimes* render one point.

Comment: You could try dividing all of your coordinates by 255.0f and then using an identity matrix for modelview and projection (e.g. comment out `gluPerspective (...)` and `gluLookAt (...)`). This will put everything into the NDC coordinate space: All points (X,Y,Z) >= -1.0 and (X,Y,Z) <= 1.0 will be visible. This can be used to rule out any camera issues.

Comment: Commented out gluPerspective and gluLookAt and only one point is still being rendered (tried diving by 255 and not dividing - same thing).

Comment: Then your problem lies somewhere else. I would suggest you paste your main render loop in its entirety. It sounds almost as though these operations are coming *after* your call to `render (...)`, which definitely is not going to do anything meaningful. Also, I noticed your `mapArray` is leaking everytime you load your terrain. You should free that memory after you call `glBufferData (...)`, because GL copies it immediately.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thats everything.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman If I move my gluLookAt() call to the PROJECTION matrix section (out of MODELVIEW matrix setion) then it works fully, I can see my terrain, it looks great. - However my understanding of OpenGL suggests that gluLookAt() should be part of the MODELVIEW matrix section(?)

Comment: Yes, `gluLookAt (...)` should be part of the ModelView matrix. You can combine ModelView and Projection but parts of the pipeline will not work correctly when you do this. The only strange thing I see in your code related to matrices is your unnecessary use of `glPushMatrix (...)` and `glPopMatrix (...)`.

Comment: Oh you are wonderful! That was it! I can't believe something so small could cause so much trouble! If you want to stick that as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I'd love to, but I honestly cannot figure out why that fixed your problem (the minimum stack depth for `GL_MODELVIEW` is 32). If I think of something, I will write an answer :P